# Create a random list from oldList and append without repeating

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, random, append

appreciate it if someone can answer this.

I have a list called as oldList which contains something like this:

```
oldList = ['a','b','c','d']
```

Then I use `random.shuffle(oldList)` to get a random list and append those into randomList.

How can I check if I run again `random.shuffle(oldList)`, and if the randomize list is already being appended into randomList, that randomize list would not be selected or append into randomList.

Comment: is it sufficient to only do it once in your code? otherwise you may find having a `set()` and a list helps you know if you already have the values

Comment: I'm not really understanding your question here. Note, `shuffle` modifies a list *in-place*, it doesn't create a new list

Comment: It's always better to include some kind of desired output. This makes it easier to understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

The `shuffle()` function returns nothing, it modifies an object in-place as pointed out by juanpa.arrivillaga.

I suspect you are looking for the `sample()` function which returns a list of items in a random order. In other words, `sample()` chooses a random sample from a population without replacement (where each item in the population has an equal chance to be picked). In the following example `k` is the random sample length.

```
from random import sample
example_list = ['a','b','c','d']
example_list.extend(sample(population=example_list, k=4))
print(example_list)
```

The order of the last four items will change each time you run this but the result will look like the following:

> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'b', 'd', 'c', 'a']

In the above example I used `extend()` instead of `append()` because the sample function outputs a list. `append()` would output something like this:

> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', ['b', 'd', 'c', 'a']]